# Why does my javascript contact-form not work?

Tags: javascript, contact-form

I have tried adapting a contact formula I found online but no matter what I do it simply will not function (It does not need to be fully functional but I need it for a live-RPG session so it needs to "feel" real). I have checked (with a validation script) and JavaScript works fine on my page, so something must be wrong with the contact forms code itself. I will be the first to admit I am not that skilled at JavaScript so I was hoping someone could take a look and see if they can spot the error, because I have spent hours and still can not get this form to work at all.

The form I am basing all this on (and thus the "finished" version is this one: https://codepen.io/cool_lazyboy/pen/QRjwpG

My own code is below

```js
    function validation() {
      var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
      var subject = document.getElementById("subject").value;
      var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
      var message = document.getElementById("message");
      var error_message = document.getElementById("error_message");
      var text;
    
      if (name.lenght <3){
      text = "Angiv venligst dit navn";
      error_message.innerHTML = text;
      return false; 
        }
    return false;
    
    }
```

```css
    .wrapper-kontakt{
      width: 100%;
      background: #fff;
      padding: 25px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(104, 104, 104, 0.8);
    }
    
    .wrapper-kontakt h2{
      text-align: center;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      letter-spacing: 3px;
      color: #332902;
    }
    
    .wrapper-kontakt .input_field{
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    
    .wrapper-kontakt .input_field input[type="text"],
    .wrapper-kontakt textarea{
      border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    
    .wrapper-kontakt textarea{
      resize: none;
      height: 80px;
    }
    
    .wrapper-kontakt .btn input[type="submit"]{
      border: 0px;
      margin-top: 15px;
      padding: 10px;
      text-align: center;
      width: 100%;
      background: #fece0c;
      color: #332902;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      letter-spacing: 5px;
      font-weight: bold;
      border-radius: 25px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    #error_message{
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      background: #fe8b8e;
      padding: 0px;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 14px;
      transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-kontakt">
      <h2>Contact us</h2>
      <div id="error_message"></div>
      <form action="" id="myform" onsubmit = "return validation();">
        <div class="input_field">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="name">
        </div>
        <div class="input_field">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Subject" id="subject">
        </div>
        <div class="input_field">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email" id="email">
        </div>
        <div class="input_field">
            <textarea placeholder="Message" id="message"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="btn">
            <input type="submit">
        </div>
      </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You've simply mis-spelled `.length`.

Answer (score 3):

Here the spelling of length is wrong :
Also check action="" on form . This attribute can also be problem

```
function validation() {
      var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
      var subject = document.getElementById("subject").value;
      var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
      var message = document.getElementById("message");
      var error_message = document.getElementById("error_message");
      var text;

      if (name.lenght <3){
      text = "Angiv venligst dit navn";
      error_message.innerHTML = text;
      return false; 
        }
    return false;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a spelling mistake in your JS in the if

```
name.lenght <3
```

Should be:

```
name.length < 3
```